# Interaction with descent of the dragons and dragon tempest

Tags: magic-the-gathering

Let's say I have 4 creatures on the battlefield, and the [Dragon Tempest](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?multiverseid=394542) enchantment out as well.

If I use [Descent of the Dragons](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?name=Descent%20of%20the%20Dragons) and replace all 4 of my creatures, how does this interact with dragon tempest?

1) 4 damage dealt to target controller or target creature (enchantment interprets all 4 dragons being placed as one event).

2) 10 damage dealt to target controller or target creature (enchantment triggers for each time dragon enters battlefield (1 dmg, 2 dmg, 3 dmg, 4 dmg)).

3) Something else entirely!

Thanks

Comment: So I see this is a duplicate, referring to this rule: 603.6a Enters-the-battlefield abilities trigger when a permanent enters the battlefield. These are written, "When [this object] enters the battlefield, ..." or "Whenever a [type] enters the battlefield, ..." Each time an event puts one or more permanents onto the battlefield, all permanents on the battlefield (including the newcomers) are checked for any enters-the-battlefield triggers that match the event.  <--- So in this situation it deals 10 damage? I still don't know if I am reading this rule correct.

Comment: If someone can just tell me how much damage it deals, instead of just marking a dupe that would be great!@

Comment: Did you read the answer in the first link? It says "whenever multiple objects enter the battlefield at the same time, their enters the battlefield triggers will all see all of them as on the battlefield." You have 4 triggers. Each of them sees all 4 dragons on the battlefield. That makes 16 total damage.